# Verify SHA1withECDSA signature on Scala

Tags: java, scala, digital-signature, ecdsa, key-pair

I am trying to write simple code for creating public/private keys, signing and verifying ECDSA signature. I have no idea why verification returns false. Please help me.

** I also tried to set provider to "SunEC" but it still doesn't work

```
val signatureECDSA = "SHA1withECDSA"

val signatureInstance = Signature.getInstance(signatureECDSA)

def sign(text: String, privateKey: PrivateKey): Array[Byte] = {

  signatureInstance.initSign(privateKey)
  signatureInstance.update(text.getBytes("UTF-8"))
  signatureInstance.sign
}

def verify(signature: Array[Byte], publicKey: PublicKey): Boolean = {

  signatureInstance.initVerify(publicKey)
  signatureInstance.verify(signature)
}

def createPrivatePublicKeyPair(): Unit = {

  val keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC")
  val ecSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256k1")
  keyGen.initialize(ecSpec)

  val keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair
  val publicKey = keyPair.getPublic
  val privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate

  val ecPrivateKey = privateKey.asInstanceOf[ECPrivateKey]
  val ecPublicKey = publicKey.asInstanceOf[ECPublicKey]

  val msg = "This is a message"

  val signature = sign(msg, ecPrivateKey)

  System.out.println("Signature: " + new BigInteger(1, signature).toString(16))

  val result = verify(signature, ecPublicKey)
  System.out.println("public key matched with signature " + result)
}
```

Comment: You must verify any digital signature, including ECDSA, against the publickey AND the data signed. Pass the same data to `signatureInstance.update` in verify as you did in sign.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks  now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature does encapsulate the **hash over the data** in some way or other. In the case of RSA signatures the hash is simply contained in the signature. In the case of ECDSA the hash is used within the signature calculation and cannot be retrieved, but it can of course still be used to verify the signature.

What is not included in the signature is the data over which the signature is calculated. Instead you need to provide the data using `signatureInstance.update(text.getBytes("UTF-8"))` in the verification method, just as in the method that generates the signature.

Comment: Provided answer so that the question can be marked as answered. Please mark as accepted if you agree with it; I've put it in as community wiki, so I won't get reputation for it.